# How do I use gdb to initialize an application which can be seen in the main screen of ipad?

Tags: ios, gdb

I need to debug a application(which I don't have the source for it) during its initialization. Using

```
gdb AppName
```

The application seems to stuck in UIApplicationMain and never call anything that belongs to the app code. However, using gdb to attach the Main screen initialzed process, we will miss out all the initialzation part.

So my question is, how to use gdb to start application which can be seen in the main screen, just as we use a finger to start it.

Thank you.